# Infinite loop in an if-else statement determining list equality

Tags: c#

I have this snippet of code that checks for size equality of a list. If their size is equal, AND if all elements of `_cachedSecondList` is equal to `secondList`, then it does nothing (though I have some debugging text in this particular example).

Otherwise, if the the `count` is equal, but the items are different in each list, then it would trigger `Menu_HandleOutOfBounds()` which refreshes the canvas.

```
if (_cachedSecondList.Count == secondList.Count)
{
    if (_cachedSecondList.SequenceEqual(secondList))
    {
        string s = String.Join(",", _cachedSecondList);
        string b = String.Join(",", secondList);
        MessageBox.Show("Second: " + s);
        MessageBox.Show("Second: " + b);
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        Menu_HandleOutOfBounds(_sender, _e);
        MessageBox.Show("Triggered Equality Check. New Index: " + _index);
    }
}
```

For some very strange reason, both the `if` and `else` are triggered in my code, and I am stuck in an infinite loop every single time.

I tried to put the `return` to exit the loops if the condition is met in the `.SequenceEqual()` conditions, but no avail.

First Messagebox:

[image]

Second Messagebox:

[image]

Third MessageBox:

[image]

Comment: Are you sure your whole code isn't called twice? Try to put breakpoints to follow the code flow, I doubt both code blocks after `if` and `else` are executed one after another.

Comment: I cannot use break-points or normal debugging methods since I am creating a class library, which gets compiled to a .dll, then used in Grasshopper 3D, and Rhino graphical programming plugin.

Comment: don't you have a `while` loop or an `foreach` before? or, if all this is in one function, isn't your function called multiple times? try puting a msgBox outside this code snipped and see if it gets called twice.

Comment: @theGreenCabbage Then use the Good Old Technique of putting MessageBox.Show() every 2 lines of code to follow what's executed.

Comment: @ken2k That's what I am doing, but to no avail. Infinite loops every where.

Comment: @theGreenCabbage I don't see any loop in your code, you should provide more background (i.e. calling code..etc)

Comment: @theGreenCabbage: can you show few more lines of code above your if statements?

Comment: im surly suspecting that your code (shown above) is in some loop , so for first iteration it executes if and next iteration it executes `else`

Comment: Hi Sudhakar, it is indeed under a loop. You're right -- I'm going to put some `MessageBox.Show()` inside the `else-statement` to see my two lists. For sure that's why it's triggering the `else.

Comment: @theGreenCabbage that's what i've been saying 5 min ago :)

Comment: Side note: consider writing unit tests for your code...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I am. That's how the issue is coming up.

Comment: @theGreenCabbage - but you've said that you can't debug it??? I never had problem debugging at least VS unit tests...

Comment: @theGreenCabbage: dear could you please share your code? or you found the issue?

Comment: I found the issue. So it appears the `else` is called infinite amount of times since the `_cachedList` and `newList` switches places every loop revision. So.. `newList = _cachedList`.. then `_cachedList = newList`.. infinitely

Comment: Hey @Mihai thanks for the suggestion. The `MessageBox.Show()` has helped me debug what the issue was. With that said, the only downfall to this is when I face an infinite loop and can't stop calculations until I open task manager to close the program.